# How can I validate url variable in DRF (Django Rest Framework) generic.ListView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to use url variables for my queryset in DRF `generic.ListView`,
but I can validate that anyway now I want know how can validate that

I wrote the following code, but it does not work.

```py
class VideoView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def validate(self):
        print("ejra")
        if "class" not in self.request.GET:
            return Response({"error": "class should exist"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        if len(Class.objects.filter(pk=self.request.GET["class"])) < 1:
            return Response({"error": "class not found"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.validate()
        class_obj = Class.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET["class"])
        queryset = Video.objects.filter(study_class=class_obj).order_by("-date")
        return queryset

    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
```

Comment: doesnt work? what's problem?

Comment: now if my url dosnt have class variable i get error and i dont have any response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could raise **`DRF API ValidationError`** from the **`validate()`** method itself,

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class VideoView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer

    def validate(self):
        if "class" not in self.request.GET:
            raise ValidationError({"error": "class should exist"})
        if Class.objects.filter(pk=self.request.GET["class"]).exists():
            raise ValidationError({"error": "class not found"})

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.validate()
        class_obj = Class.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET["class"])
        queryset = Video.objects.filter(study_class=class_obj).order_by("-date")
        return queryset
```

---

### NOTES

1. USE [DRF **`ValidationError()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror) exception to raise the error
2. Use [Django Queryset's **`exists()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) method to check if there are any objects.
3. **Never Ever** use **`len()`** function to check the ***count()*** of a Django Queryset, it's a very very bad practice.

Comment: but .exists() have some ploblem and some time i get error about them

Comment: ListAPIView doesnt have a validate method from what i can see. http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's why he called the `validate()` method in the `get_queryset()` @bbmhmmad